# Linq syntax to state explicit type instead of var

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a LINQ query to get `List<List<testobject>> results = ...`

I get the correct results using var but want to declare the explicit type rather than use `var`. What is the correct syntax to do this?

Simple example is as follows

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<testobject> testobjectList = new List<testobject>()
        {
            new testobject(){field1 = 1, field2 = "1",field3 = "1",field4 = "1", field5 = "1"},
            new testobject(){field1 = 1, field2 = "1",field3 = "1a",field4 = "1a", field5 = "1a"},
            new testobject(){field1 = 1, field2 = "1",field3 = "1b",field4 = "1b", field5 = "1b"},
            new testobject(){field1 = 2, field2 = "2",field3 = "2",field4 = "2", field5 = "2"},
            new testobject(){field1 = 3, field2 = "3",field3 = "3",field4 = "3", field5 = "3"},
            new testobject(){field1 = 4, field2 = "4",field3 = "4",field4 = "4", field5 = "4"},
            new testobject(){field1 = 4, field2 = "4",field3 = "4a",field4 = "4a", field5 = "4a"},
            new testobject(){field1 = 5, field2 = "5",field3 = "5",field4 = "5", field5 = "5"},
            new testobject(){field1 = 6, field2 = "6",field3 = "6",field4 = "6", field5 = "6"},
            new testobject(){field1 = 6, field2 = "6",field3 = "6a",field4 = "6a", field5 = "6a"},
            new testobject(){field1 = 6, field2 = "6",field3 = "6b",field4 = "6b", field5 = "6b"},
            new testobject(){field1 = 7, field2 = "7",field3 = "7",field4 = "7", field5 = "7"}

        };

        // Correct output
        var results1 = testobjectList.Where(x => x.field1 >= 2)
                                     .GroupBy(x => x.field2).ToList();

        // But how do I do the same but explicitly state type?
        List<List<testobject>> results2 = testobjectList.Where(x => x.field1 >= 2)
                                                        .GroupBy(x => x.field2).ToList();
    }
}

class testobject
{
    public int field1 { get; set; }
    public string field2 { get; set; }
    public string field3 { get; set; }
    public string field4 { get; set; }
    public string field5 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: HimBroBeere is right, but why would you like to do that ?

Comment: The actual type returned by your query should be `List<IGrouping>` (`GroupBy` will return a collection of `IGrouping`), which probably isn´t what you want. Why do you even care fr the exact type?

Comment: I want to pass the result to a function but can't pass var. I understand I could pass testobjectList instead and do this in the function but that's not always practical, hence the question. It's more learning about LINQ than anything else.

Comment: Saman answer is the good one but for future reference to know the type you can simply mouse hover the last element of the linq sequence (here it's your .ToList()) and the popup window will tell you what is the current return type (left most information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all when you are using `GroupBy` function, `var` is compiled to:

```
List<IGrouping<string,testobject>>
```

If you really want to have `List<List<testobject>>` you can use this query:

```
testobjectList.Where(x => x.field1 >= 2).GroupBy(x => x.field2).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

And if you want to have `List<testobject>` you can use:

```
testobjectList.Where(x => x.field1 >= 2).GroupBy(x => x.field2).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<List<testobject>>` wouldn't be the correct type. If you added a breakpoint on a line after and `results1` is declared and inspected the type of it you would probably see something similar to `List<IGrouping<string, testobject>>`. If you want to declare explicit types use some means to figure out actual type, like a debugger, IDE or some plugin. ReSharper could give you a refactoring option to declare explicit type instead of `var`.

Answer (score 0):

When you hover over the `ToList()` call in VisualStudio you can see that the return type is `List<IGrouping<string, testobject>>`

Try:

```
List<IGrouping<string, testobject>> results2 = testobjectList.Where(x => x.field1 >= 2)
                                                             .GroupBy(x => x.field2).ToList();
```

If you have ReSharper you can use the "Specify type explicitly" refactoring to convert the var statement to the explicit type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten your result by adding a .SelectMany() to strongly type the result as a List.

You also have the List declared as **List**<**List**> result 2 when it should be **List**

Working Sample:

```
List<testobject> results2 = testobjectList .Where(x => x.field1 >= 2)
                                                    .GroupBy(x=>x.field2)
                                                    .SelectMany(x=>x)
                                                    .ToList();
```